# How to update AIML version from 1.0.1 to AIML 2.0

Tags: aiml

Current application is using AIML version `1.0.1` and I want to update it to `2.0` . The xml files are having the code like -

```
<aiml version = "1.0.1" encoding = "UTF-8">
<aiml>
    <category>
        <name>URL</name>
        <pattern>Example link*</pattern>
        <template>Here is the Link !
        <hyperlink href="https://example.com"target="_blank">Click Here</hyperlink>
        <id>URL1</id>
    </template>
    </category>
</aiml>
```

Answer (score 2):

Which bot are you using?

AIML 2.0 is fully compatible with 1.0

Comment: I am using pandorabots

Answer (score 2):

Documentation about AIML (including AIML 2) is available here: https://pandorabots.com/docs/aiml-reference/

Your example category can now be simplified to this, using the <link> tag

```
<category>
    <pattern>Example link</pattern>
    <template>Here is the Link !
        <link>
            <text>Click here</text>
            <url>https://example.com</url>
        </link>
    </template>
</category>
```